# Application state variables or session state variables in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Want to load master data on Application_start event of MVC application, so that it can be used through out the life cycle of application irrespective of user session.
Similarly for each user login want to load user data and cache it for further usage.
How to do both things in ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: Which IoC container are you planning to use?

Comment: `MemoryCache` for app wide data, `Session` for user specific data

Answer (score 0):

using System.Runtime.Caching;

```
protected ObjectCache Cache => MemoryCache.Default;

public virtual T Get<T>(string key)
{
    return (T)Cache[key];
}

public virtual void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
{
    if (data == null) return;

    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime)
    };

    Cache.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
}
```

.Net Core Have distributed memory cache. Otherwise Redis will be the right choice with same logic...

That's it... :)

Comment: Implement same code for LongTermCache and ShortTermCache (Per-Request)... Use pattern for release all paramters In Session_End...  'public static void RemoveByPattern(this ICacheManager cacheManager, string pattern, IEnumerable<string> keys)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach (var key in keys.Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p.ToString())).ToList())
                cacheManager.Remove(key);
        }'

Comment: I use for this IShortTermCache and ILongTermCache. I use AutoFac IoC. that's good for me..

Comment: One potential issue with this approach is that you are bound to a single web server (since `MemoryCache` is machine specific).

Comment: You are right. .Net Core Have distributed memory cache. Otherwise Redis will be the right choice with same logic...